# Generator of a group cannot be a generator of a proper subgroup

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

While solving problem on cyclic group, I have noticed that **Generator of every proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_n}$ cannot generate the whole $\mathbb{Z_n}$ or equivalently, generator of $\mathbb{Z_n}$ cannot generate a proper subgroup of  $\mathbb{Z_n}$.**
I try to prove this assumption. 
Let **m** be a order **d** generator of a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_n}$. So $n=dk$ for some integer $k$ and $d<n$. Therefore $<m>=\{0, m,\ldots, (d-1)m\}$. Now $(d-1)<(n-1)$, so $|<m>|\neq n=|\mathbb{Z_n}|$.
 Now my question is whether this assumption and the supporting reasoning are correct. Also, if the assumption is correct, can we say in general that Generators of a cyclic group cannot generate a proper subgroup?
Thank you.

Comment: Use the order $m$ of an element Then the claim is immediately clear. For $C_n$ we have $o(g)=n$. For a proper subgroup, we have $o(a)=m$, a proper divisor of $n$. Hence $a$ cannot generate $C_n$.

Comment: Your statement sounds tautological to me! If it geenrates a proper subgroup then it does not generate the whole group, because a proper subgroup is by definition not equal to the whole group.

Comment: Maybe this will help:  "Let $G$ be a group, $g \in G$, and let < $g$ > = { $g^n | n \in \mathbb{Z}$ }. Then <$g$> is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $g$."

Comment: @Dietrich Burde sir, should I edit the question because I think this is true for finite cyclic group